# Example of orientable surface $M\subset\mathbb{R^n}$ such that has no normal vector fields

Tags: smooth-manifolds, orientation

There is the following well known result about manifolds in $\mathbb{R^n}$:

Theorem: Let $M\subset\mathbb{R^n}$ be a surface (manifold) of class $C^k$ $k\geq 1$ and dimension $m$. If there are $n-m$ continuous normal ($v_{i}(p)$ belongs to the orthogonal complement of $T_{p}M$ for all $p\in M$ and $i$) vector fields $v_1,\dots,v_{n-m}:M\to\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $v_1(p),\dots,v_{n-m}(p)$ are lienarly independent for each $p\in M$, then $M$ is orientable.

The conversely of the above result is not true if $n-m>1$. So I want to find some example of an orientable surface that does not admit such kind of vector fields, I searched about that but it was fruitless. Someone know where can I find such a example?

Comment: Does a closed line in $\mathbb R^3$ always admit such vector fields? All lines are orientable.

Comment: I think so. For example, let $(a,b,c)$ the vector that define the direction of that line, so if we complete a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$ which $(a,b,c)$ is one of those, then the other two vector defines such a vector field (constant vector field)

Comment: Right. I was thinking of a curved line. Locally you can define such vector fields at each point, but can you paste them smoothly?

Comment: Can you give an example of such curve?

Comment: Do you know characteristic classes?  Any embedding of $\mathbb{C}P^m$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an example of what you're looking for.